# Get custom field from list item with powershell

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, powershell

I've the following code to retrieve list items and select properties:

```
$list = $web.Lists["MyCustomList"]
$listItems = $list.GetItems()
$items = $listItems | select "MyCustomFieldName"
```

This does not work tho (I've tried with ex. 'Title' and it works), how could I retrieve the custom field? If I do the following, it gives me the value:

```
$listItems[0]["MyCustomFieldName"]
```

Comment: Do you see the custom column when you use "Select * "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ask me to explain how this works, but try:

```
$items = $listItems | select @{ Label="MyCustomFieldName";Expression={$_["MyCustomFieldName"]}}
```

or an alternate, if you don't mind looping instead of using select:

```
 $items = $listItems | % { $_["MyCustomFieldName"] }
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27373810/1452528